# Creating a string replacement loop in Python

Tags: python, string, function, loops, replace

I'm fairly new to python and programming in general so bear with me please.
I'm attempting to create a function that will take a given string input and remove any of the spaces contained between the words.

My code as it stands now:

```
def convertName(oldName):
    newName = oldName
    while newName == oldName:
        newName = oldName.replace("  "," ",)
    return newName

name = str(input("Name ---- "))
newName = convertName(name)
print("Result --",newName)
```

Currently, all of my attempts to make this loop work have either resulted in the process only being done once, or an infinite loop. I understand that as soon as my loop runs the first time that newName is no longer equal to oldName so my while statement is now false. Any hints/tips would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too much work.

```
newname = re.sub('  +', ' ', oldname)
```

Comment: Hey, this solution worked pretty well, only one problem I have with it now. If the input of newName contains X number of spaces before it the print statement also shows 1 space before the name. 
For example: if newName = Josh      example     example
it prints: Josh example example
however, if I put any number of spaces before "Josh", my print result will contain 1 space prior to the name.
newName =        Josh    example    example
print(newName) yields:  Josh example example
Any thoughts?

Comment: Then you need to do it again, substituting `'^ +'` with `''`.

Comment: Which part is it that I replace? I don't think there was a '^ +'

Comment: Hmmm, I'm still unable to produce the correct result. I've tried several variations of what you had. Any hints you could give without giving away the answer? Thanks for the help.

Comment: `... = re.sub('^ +', ...)`

Answer (score 1):

As you say your `while` condition is false , a better way for this problem is `split` the string and concatenate with one space :

```
>>> s= 'a  b b   r'
>>> ' '.join(s.split())
'a b b r'
```

and if you are not sure of the number of spaces you could use regular expressions :

```
>>> re.sub(r'\s+',' ',s)
'a b b r'
```

`\s+` match any combine of whitespace !

Answer (score 0):

If the string doesn’t have any double-spaces in it to begin with, `newName` will always be equal to `oldName`. Rather than replace while there’s been no change since last time, you need to stop replacing when there *has* been a change since last time.

```
def convert_name(old_name):
    while True:
        # Replace any double-spaces in the current string
        new_name = old_name.replace('  ', ' ')

        if new_name == old_name:
            # String isn’t changing anymore, so there were
            # no double-spaces; return
            return new_name

        # Check the next replacement against this version
        old_name = new_name
```

Regular expressions work better here, though:

```
import re

def convert_name(name):
    return re.sub(' {2,}', ' ', name)
```